# socket.emit run function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with node.js and trying to run a function on an button click.

```
var field = document.getElementById("field");

sendButton.onclick = function() {
        var text = field.value;

        //This works
        socket.emit('send', { message: text, username: name.value });

        //This works
        socket.emit('send', { message: "I am a dog", Username: name.value });

        //This does NOT work
        givePoints(false);

};

//my function
var givePoints = function(answer) {
    if (answer == false) {
        $('#dogStats').html(function (i, val) { return val * 1 + 1; });
    }
};
```

So my question is, how can I run the `givePoints`-function och the button-click? I'm a newbie on node.js so any help would be appreciated

Comment: This problem isn't really specific to Node.js, it's a general JS issue. What value do you expect to pass into `givePoints`?

Comment: @James Not really shure what you mean. I'm passing in a false value in the function. And if it is false I put a counter to the #dogStats-div. I'm a bit lost. How do I get the funtion to run and so the value is set into #dogStats?

Comment: Where is `sendButton` assigned? If it's a button on the UI then you should really just use jQuery to assign the click event e.g. `$('#buttonId').click(function(e) { givePoints(false); });`

Comment: Okay. That was the way I was doing it first. But thought it would be better to do it in node.js. Counclution is I need to read the node-docs more. Thanks!

Comment: Again, this isn't related to Nodejs - Node is a *server*-side process, the trouble you are having is on the client.

Comment: Without jquery one option is: document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener("click", function(){givePoints(false);});